# Is there a reason this would show as a blank page?

Tags: html

Edit: I moved the `img` from `head` to `body`. I also edited the embed link format. I am still getting the blank page issue. Please find the updated code below.

Additional Info: I am working on VS Code and the issue happens when I try to open the code in default browser.

I am learning HTML and had an assignment to make a quick page for my favorite musical artist. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but when I go to view on Chrome, I get a blank page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <title>Fruitful Melodies</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img
    src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/alfonso-castro-caloncho-poses-for-photo-during-a-black-carpet-as-part-picture-id1349969739?s=2048x2048"
    alt="Caloncho at the Vogue Magazine 'Dia de Muertos' Gala - Black Carpet"
    width="455"
    length="682"
    />

    <h1>Bio</h1>

    <p>
      Born Óscar Alfonso Castro, Caloncho is a Mexican musician and singer. His unique style mixes traditional Mexican sounds and rhythms with reggae and urban beats. His lyricism ranges from playful folk tales to deeply reflective pieces on fatherood and our place in this world.
    </p>

    <p>
      Caloncho has enjoyed much success since his debut EP <em>Homeotermo</em> in 2011. He has earned two Latin Grammy nominations and has won various Independent Music Awards. His newest album, <em>Buen pez</em>, was released in June 2022 and sees Caloncho collaborate with artists from a wide variety of genres. 
    </p>

    <a href="https://www.caloncho.mx/">Caloncho's Official Website</a>

    <h2>Discography</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>2011, <em>Homeotermo</em></li>
      <li>2013, <em>Fruta</em></li>
      <li>2015, <em>Fruta Vol. II</em></li>
      <li>2017, <em>Bálsamo</em></li>
      <li>2022, <em>Buen Pez</em></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Favorite Song</h2>

    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/626PsX2fj0k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why in the world do you have an `img` tag in your `head`?? Get that out of there!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know `img` in `head`

I removed it and placed it in `body` but I am still having the blank page issue.

Comment: It looks like it runs fine on the `Run code snippet` on stackoverflow. Are you sure this file is identical, is formatted with `.html` at the end of the file, browser issues, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Img tags must be inside of body. It works on head, but its not suitable.

I believe the embed link format you used is incorrect. Use the following code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/626PsX2fj0k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I removed the img tag from the head and placed it inside of body. I also corrected the embed link format. Unfortunately, I am still having the blank page issue.